# In react useEffect hook my functions are called but only first function can change the state second function can't change the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { deleteItem, getCartItems } from "../../services/cartService";
import { BsFillTrash2Fill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { MdOutlineRemoveShoppingCart } from "react-icons/md";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./cart.css";

const Cart = ({ user }) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  let [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
  const shopping = useRef(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const tot = useRef(null);

  const myCart = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getCartItems().then((response) => {
        setItem(response.data[0].cartItems);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  //Delete item from cart

  const handleRemoveItem = (itemId) => {
    swal({
      title: "Remove from cart?",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    }).then(async (willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        const res = await deleteItem(itemId);
        myCart();
      }
    });
  };

  // Contunue Shopping

  const handleShopping = () => {
    navigate("/product");
  };

  const totalPrice = () => {
    item.map((it) => {
      setTotalAmount((totalAmount += it.product.price));
    });
    console.log(totalAmount);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    myCart();
    totalPrice();
  }, []);

  if (!item) return null;

  console.log(item);

  if (user && item.length !== 0) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="md:flex flex-row mt-24 text-2xl justify-evenly hidden">
          <div>Items</div>
          <div>Item Name</div>
          <div>Item Price</div>
          <div>Quantity</div>
          <div>Total Item Price</div>
          <div>Action</div>
        </div>
        {item.map((cartItem) => (
          <div
            className="flex flex-col w-full md:mt-0 mt-20"
            key={cartItem.product._id}
          >
            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-6 grid-cols-2 gap-4 md:gap-0 items-center text-center pt-2 pb-2 shadow-md shadow-black">
              <div className="h-56 grid place-items-center">
                <img
                  src={"http://" + cartItem.product.images?.host}
                  alt="image"
                  className="md:h-46 h-36 max-w-full"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="md:text-lg font-bold text-xl md:h-auto h:56 truncation">
                {cartItem.product.name}
              </div>
              <div className="text-4xl font-bold">
                ₹ {cartItem.product.price}
              </div>
              <div className="">
                <div className="text-3xl font-bold md:pe-16">
                  {cartItem.quantity}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div
                className="text-4xl font-bold"
                ref={tot}
                value={cartItem.product.price * cartItem.quantity}
              >
                {cartItem.product.price * cartItem.quantity}
              </div>
              <div className="text-4xl text-red-600 cursor-pointer ">
                <BsFillTrash2Fill
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleRemoveItem(cartItem._id);
                  }}
                />
                {/* {console.log(cartItem._id)} */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

        <div className="mt-5 grid grid-cols-6 w-full place-items-end gap-5">
          <div className="text-4xl font-bold col-span-4">Total Amount:</div>
          <div className="text-4xl font-bold w-full">{totalAmount}</div>
        </div>

        <div
          className="btn-shadow"
          ref={shopping}
          onMouseDown={(e) => {
            e.target.classList.add("btn-shadow-click");
          }}
          onMouseUp={(e) => {
            e.target.classList.remove("btn-shadow-click");
          }}
          onClick={handleShopping}
        >
          Continue Shopping
        </div>
        {/* <div onClick={totalPrice}>getToatl</div> */}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="flex flex-col md:min-h-[500px] min-h-screen justify-center items-center">
          <MdOutlineRemoveShoppingCart size={100} color="purple" />
          <h2 className="font-roboto">No Items Added to the Cart</h2>
          <Link to="/product">
            <button className="p-3 border border-solid border-purple-800 w-full text-center font-bold text-xl rounded-full duration-700 bg-purple-800 text-white cursor-pointer hover:bg-white hover:text-purple-800 no-underline">
              Start Shopping
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default Cart;
```

In this code In useEffect 'myCart' function first returns a blank array and then  returns the responsed array. But my 'totalPrice' calculation is calculated before loading the array. So it is not rendering the desired output. How to stop getting the blank array or getting rid fron this situation.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`totalAmount` is directly dependent on `item` and thus it isn't (shouldn't be) it's own state.

remove `totalAmount`, `setTotalAmount` and `totalPrice` and replace it with

```js
const totalAmount = item.reduce((sum, it) => {
  return sum + it.product.price;
}, 0);
```

now `totalAmount` will always be the sum of all prices in `item`.

on another note, you should never declare a react state with `let`, as done for `totalAmount`. `totalAmount += it.product.price` is a dangerous approach and might lead to unexpected behavior as you are reassigning `totalAmount` manually.

Comment: Thank You so much Sir for the answer and the advice. Problem solved. I will never declare with let again. Thank You So Much again.